# Permissions on django media directory

Tags: django, macos

This may be a question for server fault but since it involves a django app, here goes:

I have a django app that allows files to be uploaded to the media directory via file upload fields.

```
def content_file_name(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join([ instance.client, instance.job_number, instance.post_type + "_" + instance.post_round, instance.job_number + "-" + instance.cell_number, filename])

class PostEntry(models.Model):
        ...
        add_pdf = models.NullBooleanField()
        link_pdf = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name, blank=True, null=True)
        add_html = models.NullBooleanField()
        link_html = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name, blank=True, null=True)
        add_zip = models.NullBooleanField()
        link_zip = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name, blank=True, null=True)
        ...
```

I've also made the media directory available to other users via ftp. Although I've set the permissions on the media directory to allow read, write and execute recursively on all files and subdirectories within it, it still won't allow ftp operations on any subdirectory django creates after I've set permissions. Which is to say, if I access my newly created subdirectory (within my media directory) through an ftp client, I don't, by default, have privileges to drag a file into, or delete a file from said directory.

In settings, I've set the FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS option at 0644. As I expected, it made no difference. Is there ANY way to set django so that it creates directories that can be written to outside of the application? Or is this behavior that has to be set at the OS level?

Comment: What system user is your ftp server running as, and what system user does your django webserver run as?

Comment: They're both running off of OS X 10.5 (an old Leopard box, apache2 instance). I'm not sure I understand the system user questions but I think I created them while I was logged in as an "admin" user.

Comment: Ahh. OS X. Thought this was Linux. Not sure then.

Comment: What user is your apache web server running as? newly created directories from your django app are going to be owned by whoever is running the process. Most servers will run all apache processes using the www-data user or something, but for django, I think most apps will run wsgi which allows you to set who the user and group of the process are via the WSGIDaemonProcess directive in the apache conf. You may need to add your django user and ftp users into a group, because all uploads will be owned by whoever the django user was that wrote them to disk and make the files group writable.

Comment: this is awesome info! I'm away from the server now but will implement asap in the am. thanks yellott.